# Printing file name of with a string

Tags: file

Goal: is to print the name of every .c program in a directory specified by first argument that contains some word.

My idea was:

```
word = "word"
for file in specifiedDirectory with c file extension
do 
if grep -w $word $file ; then
echo $file
fi
done
```

Comment: You could also use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com/) e.g. `ack goto`; but what about `#define JUMP goto` in a header file, and `JUMP lab;` in a `*.c` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `GNU grep` you can also just do

```
grep -rwl --include '*.c' word specifiedDirectory
```

With relevant options from [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

```
-r, --recursive
      Read  all  files  under  each directory, recursively, following symbolic links only if they are on the command line.
      This is equivalent to the -d recurse option.
-w, --word-regexp
      Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches that form whole words.  The test is that the matching substring must
      either be at the beginning of the line, or preceded by a non-word constituent  character.   Similarly,  it  must  be
      either  at  the  end  of  the line or followed by a non-word constituent character.  Word-constituent characters are
      letters, digits, and the underscore.
-l, --files-with-matches
      Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print  the  name  of  each input file from which output would normally have been
      printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is specified by POSIX.)
--include=GLOB
      Search only files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard matching as described under --exclude).
```

Answer (score 1):

With a modern find the following should do what you want.

```
wordfind() {
    find "$1" -name '*.c' -exec grep -wl word {} \+
}
```

You could also spit all the files out and use `xargs` to try to cut down the number of times `grep` needs to be run.

Something like this.

```
wordfind() {
    find "$1" -name '*.c' -print0 | xargs -0 -r grep -wl word
}
```

Use `"$@"` in place of `"$1"` in either of the above functions to support passing multiple directories to the functions instead of just one directory. (Also adds support for supplying arbitrary arguments to find but that's a different topic entirely.)

Comment: Would there be a way to do this without functions, seeing as we haven't really covered this in our lectures yet. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Zaid_em Stick the body line of either function in a file and it'll be a shell script and work just the same.

Comment: I tried this and got the following error: find: missing argument to `-exec'. Any ideas?

Comment: @Zaid_em You probably have an older version of `find`, which hasn't caught up to the current posix standard. Switch `+` for `\;` or use the `xargs` option (note `xargs` will almost always be faster than `-exec ... \;` for commands that can take multiple files as arguments)

Comment: Older and non-GNU versions of find will likely also not have `-print0` which means manually doing that (if `xargs -0` works) or manually looping over find output (and losing the `xargs` multiple files at once benefit) or using `find` and `xargs` without `-print0` and `-0` and being less safe in the face of arbitrary file names.

Comment: @EtanReisner the error seemed to be a mistake on my part, all is working fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s globstar
word="word"
for file in path/to/**/*.c
do 
    grep -l -w "$word" "$file"
done
```

Notes:

- To avoid unpleasant surprises, always put shell variables, like `word` or `file` in double-quotes as shown above.  Tnis prevents word-splitting.
- With the `-l` option, `grep` will print the name of any matching file.  This makes the `if` and `echo` statements unnecessary.
- In order to search a whole directory tree, we use bash's `globstar` feature.  This enables `**/` to match zero or more directories.  (On Mac OSX, this feature is not available unless you have upgraded to `bash` version 4.0 or better.)
- In `bash` assignment statements, there can be no spaces on either side of the equal sign.  Let's consider how `bash` looks at the line:

  ```
  word = "word"
  ```

  As `bash` interprets that line, it will try to execute the command `word` with two arguments: `=` and `word`.  If that is not what you want,  the spaces must be removed.

#### Further simplification

`grep` will accept multiple filenames on its command line.  So, there is no need for the `for` loop:

```
shopt -s globstar
word="word"
grep -l -w "$word" path/to/**/*.c
```

#### Enhancement: providing the directory to search on the command line

Suppose we want to run the script as `./word someDirectory` and have it search the `someDirectory` tree for the `c` files.  In the script that the first argument can be referenced as `$1`.  So, create a file named `goto` which its execute bit set (`chmod +x word`) with the contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
word="word"
for file in "$1"/**/*.c
do 
    grep -l -w "$word" "$file"
done
```

Likewise for the simplified version:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
word="word"
grep -l -w "$word" "$1"/**/*.c
```

Comment: Doesn't handle sub-directories. You would need `**` globbing to handle that.

Comment: @EtanReisner You are right.  As I read the code in the question, `specifiedDirectory` looked singular.  The text, however, talks about a tree.  I will add `**`.

Comment: `word = "goto"` is not a valid shell assignment line for the record.

Comment: @EtanReisner Right again.

Comment: @Zaid_em You would replace `path/to/` with a variable (like `"$1"` in my answer below for the first script argument) that contains the path to search under.